# Why does not log transformation make the data normalized?

Tags: python, preprocessing

Having some skewed features as shown in the following figure. I am trying to imply log transformation to the feature called `vBMD(mgHA/cm3)`. I run the following codes

[image: Distribution Plots]

> import numpy as np
>
> import pandas as pd
>
> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
>
> df=pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
>
> scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
>
> df['vBMD (mgHA/cm3)']=scaler.fit_transform(np.array(df['vBMD
>   (mgHA/cm3)']).reshape(-1,1))
>
> df['vBMD (mgHA/cm3)']=np.log(np.array(df['vBMD (mgHA/cm3)']))

After the transfromation, I have got the following result.
[image: After transformation]

While I am waiting that the feature will be normalized, its skewness increased. Thus, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log transformation leads to a normal distribution only for [log-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). Not all distributions are log-normal, meaning they will not become normal after the log transformation.

**EDIT:**

As you have commented, if you are trying to convert an *arbitrary* distribution to normal, methods like [QuantileTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html) can be used. But note that these transformations make a distribution normal by changing (destroying) some information from the original data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figure out the main idea. In my case, to make mentioned feature normalize, can I use **QuantileTransformer** such as `quantile_transformer = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal', random_state=0)` `df['vBMD (mgHA/cm3)'] = quantile_transformer.fit_transform(np.array(df['vBMD (mgHA/cm3)']).reshape(-1,1))`